# android: window leak for alert dialog on sherlock activity

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

i am using menu on actionbar in SherlockFragment, onClick opens an alert dialog , this works fine , but if i go back while dialog does not show up , application crashes and log cat saying window leak , i have tried to dismiss the dialog on OnPause and OnStop but did not work for me

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
            getSherlockActivity());
    builder.setTitle(messageTitle)
            .setMessage(message)
            .setCancelable(false)
            .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            })
            .setPositiveButton("Yes",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                        }

                    });
    AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
    alert.show();
```

Comment: change the following code alertDialog = builder.show();
then in onDestory() method call alertDialog.dismiss();

Comment: Post your complete code

Comment: instead of getSherlockActivity()); use MyActivity.this it will help

Comment: How were you dismissing the dialog in onPause(), would like to see.

Comment: @Darpan i have declared AlertDialog globally and onPause check if (builder != null) { builder.dismiss();}

Comment: @SyedRazaMehdi actually i am using this in SherlockFragment not in sherlockActivity , sorry

Comment: @Darpan but this is not working for me , because in sherlock activity i am creating a tab with two sherlock fragments for two tabs , and i want to dismiss it in sherlock fragment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You gotta do it this way -
declare `Alertdialog alert = null;` globally;

then on `onPause()` check if `alert!=null`, 

and
`alert.dismiss();`

Comment: this works fine for 2.3 above but not for 2.3v n below ?

Comment: I don't have idea about it, which support library you are using for  enabling sherlokFragment in 2.3v below?

Comment: import com.actionbarsherlock.app.ActionBar;
import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragmentActivity;

Comment: Did you check this code on 2.3 below? because I checked and there was no dependency so far on versions for alert's dismission.

Comment: by doing all this stuff on onDestroy() fixed everything , thanks @Darpan